How to determine the torque required to decelerate a rotating arm?
I am working in CAD on a robotic arm and wondering what is the appropriate way to determine Torque required from my actuator to decelerate the arm moving at some speed.
Below I included a quick sketch to show an actuator attached to a pivot and some odd shaped arm extends from it which I know the Center of Mass (COM) of from CAD. The COM is some distance $R$ away from the pivot and moves at some speed $\omega$.
In the equation for torque $$T = I\alpha$$ I am unsure of how to utilize the Moment of Inertia for an odd shaped object or directly utilize COM to do this calculation. I would like to know if this is correct equation to look at and if there is a faster way through the use of COM.

How did you determine the COM from CAD?

I use a software called OnShape which calculates the COM of each individual object automatically and if multiple objects it does the summation based on standard equations.

@you can use the same idea to determine the moment of inertia of your robot arm. Divide the volume of your robot arm  into standard shapes that approximate the arm and then use moment of inertia tables to determine the moment of inertia of each shape about the COM. You can add the moments of inertia to obtain the total moment of inertia about the COM. Then use the parallel axis theorem to determine the moment of inertia about the pivot point.


I would like to know if this is correct equation to look at and if
there is a faster way through the use of COM.

It's the correct equation, but the moment of inertia about the pivot depends on how the mass is distributed about the pivot. Knowing only the location of the COM doesn't tell you what that distribution is. If you knew the moment of inertia about the COM then you could determine the moment of inertia about the pivot point (or any point on the arm) by using the parallel axis theorem
$$I_{pivot}=I_{COM}+Md^2$$
Where $M$ is the mass of the arm and $d$ is the distance from the COM to the pivot.
For the general equation for determining the moment of inertia for your arm see the last slide in the following link: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mi.html
For an example of the application of the parallel axis theorem about the end of a uniform rod see: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mi2.html#irod3
Hope this helps.
